# How to show a Details on a windows form different users on different times statically.

Tags: c#, winforms

I am developing a system (windows application) using C sharp. I want to show details inserted to a form by the user to another 
user when his login time through an another login.

Eg: Form A has a text box. the user x is typing some text in the text box. then the user y is logging to the system and open Form A. now the user y should appear the texts in the text box entered by user x.

I have no idea about this.please help me to achieve this.
if there is a technology or third party tools to do this please let me know.

Comment: is your application has DataBase Support?

Comment: Are users on same pc? Is it remote computers? Do text must appear immediately or just after login? Please update question with more details because it is very broad and add code parts where you had troubles.

Comment: Reniuz- Not on the same pc. different users are using  different computers

Comment: If you looking for char like application, you can really find many examples if you put a bit of effort in search.

Comment: Joseph- yes the  database driven application . but cant v do it using xml or something without using databases

Comment: I would have a look into SignalR. I think that would do what you want. Perhaps set up a hub for each active form, then let admins "subscribe" to them to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is write the contents of the textbox (and other controls) to a data file (or text file) in the following path:

```
string appData = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData);
```

You need to create a folder for your data file first. Problem is that only the creator has read/write access; other users have only read access. This can be fixed by setting the security options. [This link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/61987/Allow-write-modify-access-to-CommonApplicationData) might help you further.